# Remove characters in a string without multiple calls to str.replace

Tags: python, string, replace

I'm doing this project for my class and I was just wondering if would it be possible if I could replace a list of vowels, Uppercase and Lowercase in just one line instead of how I have it. This is in Python.

I would like it to be a bit more simple then writing this out completely

Thanks

```
s= input ('Enter a Sentence: ')
s = str(s.replace ('a',''))
s = str(s.replace ('e',''))
s = str(s.replace ('i',''))
s = str(s.replace ('o',''))
s = str(s.replace ('u',''))
s = str(s.replace ('A',''))
s = str(s.replace ('E',''))
s = str(s.replace ('I',''))
s = str(s.replace ('O',''))
s = str(s.replace ('U',''))
print (s)
```

Comment: Do not put the accepted answer in the question. Instead, *accept* the answer by clicking the check next to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `re` module

```
import re
s= input('Enter a Sentence: ')
re.sub('[AEIOUaeiou]','',s)
```

Comment: No i mean like i tried lol it gave me AEIOUaeiou is not defined

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`str.translate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate) and a [dict comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries):

```
>>> 'aeiouAEIOU'.translate({ord(x):None for x in 'aeiouAEIOU'})
''
>>>
```

The dict comprehension is used to create a mapping for `str.translate` of what characters should be translated into what.  Mapping characters to `None` causes the method to remove them.

Note that you could also use [`str.maketrans`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.maketrans) instead of the dict comprehension:

```
>>> 'aeiouAEIOU'.translate(str.maketrans('', '', 'aeiouAEIOU'))
''
>>>
```